# Non-return valve with hydraulic separator

Tags: plumbing, water, valve, heat-pump, floorheating

To ensure one-directional flow on a closed loop in underfloor heating systems I believe I need to get some non-return valves. Currently, my issue is the exotic nature of the system where I need to have a hydraulic separator. As per documentation, there are 3 possible states for hydraulic separator:

[image]

So far, this is my setup (feel free to point out errors):

[image: xx]

**Question:** Where can I put non-return valves (marked with a [green star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Zeu.png)) in such a way as to not compromise the hydraulic separator nor anything else?

I was thinking **x1** and **x4** but I am hardly an expert.

Comment: You show the loop as driven by a pump. Why do you think it might ever try to flow backward?

Comment: What parts of your heating system do you want to protect from reversed flow and why/when could it occur there in the first place?

Comment: It appears that your plan is far more complicated, with many more components than is necessary.   A pump, safety valve,  and shutoff valve is about all that is needed.

Comment: @keshlam it felt like I need one so I just asked to be safe than sorry. but that's actually a good point. now I am thinking **x6** to prevent pressure buildup to backflow and reach filter, separator and a pump (?) am I being just overly paranoid?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I believe the pump should be somehow protected from pressure buildup that passes back from the expansion tank and the unit itself (?)

Comment: @RMDman thought so too but distributor of heat pump unit insists on hydraulic separator and EV due to extremely large loops I have (5 loops each 200m) otherwise I will immediately lose 10-year warranty from them. its a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system like you showed does not need non-return valves as a backflow prevention mechanism.

In the comments you mentioned a concern about pressure buildup from the expansion vessel and that causing a backflow. That concern shows a misunderstanding of the purpose of an expansion vessel.

When water gets heated, either it increases in volume, or it increases in pressure. The purpose of an expansion vessel is to give the water in the closed circuit of your heating system a space to expand into, to avoid that you get a pressure build-up as a result of heating the water.

The expansion vessel will not suddenly release a volume of water with a higher pressure into the system. Additionally, a typical control of a heating system keeps the pumps running for some time after the heat source has stopped adding heat to the water. This creates a much larger flow (in the desired direction) than could ever happen naturally to equalize pressures within the system.

> thought so too but distributor of heat pump unit insists on hydraulic separator and EV due to extremely large loops I have (5 loops each 200m)

It is very likely that the integrated pump of your heat-pump unit is not powerful enough to overcome the resistance of those long water loops. Then you need an additional pump for your long circuit and having two pumps in one water circuit without a hydraulic separator is just asking for trouble, because the pumps will interfere with each other's operation.

Comment: I see, so the answer is: "I don't need any non-return valve on this whole loop" right?

Comment: @servant0, that is correct.